# Android: How can I Change the SearchView hint text color?

Tags: android, material-design, searchview

following is my code snippet for reference

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>
```

by using this   `android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"`   things not work. any help appreciated!

Comment: @Abhishekkumar that example is not the support library, probably the action bar sherlock.

Comment: can you post your code @MohdQasim

Comment: @Abhishekkumar i edited my question with xml code

Comment: can you post your java code of searchview  too @MohdQasim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i solve my problem by using fallowing changes in code

```
 search = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
    // search.setQueryHint("search");
    searchEditText = (EditText)search.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    searchEditText.setHint("search here for quick access");
```

I comment search.setQueryHint("search"); method. and I access EditText of the searchview, and call the searchEditText.setHint("search here for quick access");

Comment: If you are using android its now found here.  findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)

Answer (score 3):

**initialize it**

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.viewSearch);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search For Anything"); ---hint that is to be displayed
    LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout)searchView.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout)first.getChildAt(2);
    LinearLayout third = (LinearLayout)second.getChildAt(1);
**strong text**    
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)third.getChildAt(0);
```

-------this will change the query hint color

```
autoComplete.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray2));
```

-----this will change the query text color

```
autoComplete.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to change your searchView hint color

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="SearchViewTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
<item name="android:maxWidth">10000dp</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
```

**searchView** :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

**Or, Try to setHintColor by java :**

```
search = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchEditText = (EditText)search.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: Do you have toolbar, Its default or custom toolbar in your activity.xml @MohdQasim

Comment: this one also try but no change. just cursor color will change not hint text color @abhishek kumar

Comment: Does not work...ugh